# Git still asking for secret key after deletion?

Tags: windows, git, github, gnupg

I previously had created a GPG key for signing my Git commits to Github. I wanted to remove it, however after deleting it from Github and my local machine Git still gives me the `error: gpg failed to sign the data` when committing.

I have checked that the key is deleted from my machine since both

```
gpg --list-keys
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
```

return empty in my terminal.

I have removed the key from Git on my machine by using

```
git config --global --unset user.signingkey
```

but alas Git still gives me the error.

I'm using a Windows 10 machine for this, any clue as to what I can do?

Comment: Was it definitely in global config? I'd check the repo local config too. What about commit.gpgsign? And you're not passing -S to git commit in a script somewhere either are you?

Comment: @Rup I tried both with and without --global (while in the repo directory) so I'm assuming that covers "repo local config". Definitely not passing -S in the commit. Not sure what `commit.gpgsign` is though. No such file is in the directory's `.git` folder if thats any help.

Comment: It’s another config setting, the one that means -S by default.

Comment: @Rup haha! fantastic, it worked! Thanks very much, never would have found that otherwise. Is there a list of the config settings somewhere that I can take a look at? I'd also be happy to accept an answer if you posted one.

Comment: I don't know, sorry, I found in [someone's instructions for setting up signing](https://gist.github.com/mort3za/ad545d47dd2b54970c102fe39912f305). I'd guess there would be in the git manual somewhere, but I couldn't find it at first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn off signing by default you'll also need to clear the commit.gpgsign config setting:

```
git config --global --unset commit.gpgsign
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can try

1. `gpg --list-keys`
2. `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG`
3. `git config --global --unset commit.gpgsign`
   and you will not have a error
   but with `git config --global --unset user.signingkey` maybe you will have this warning

   warning: user.signingkey has multiple values